# Unbound Local Error within multiple Functions

Tags: python

I've been creating a series of random events where each function does something different to a main set of variables, yet I keep getting unbound local errors. Here's a watered down version of the barebones of my code

```
  variable = 1

  def main():
     global variable
     secondary()
     variable = secondary()

 def secondary()
    variable += 1
    return variable
```

once again this is a really minimal way to explain my code but the variable += 1 is the part that is expressing the error

Answer (score 4):

I noted all of the same issues that @TimothyChen mentioned.  I'd like to explain the error you're asking about, which is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v' referenced before assignment
```

That happens here:

```
v = 1

def secondary()
    v += 1
```

The issue here is due to a behavior that is unique to Python, and a little strange (please excuse that I changed the name `variable` to `v` to avoid confusion)...

If there is a global variable declared named `v`, and then you only read from a variable named `v` inside a function, Python declares that you are reading from the global variable named `v`.

If there is a global variable declared named `v`, and then you write to a variable named `v` inside a function, Python says that that's a different variable local to the function unless you first say `global v` in that function, after which point `v` refers to the global variable.

So the case of your function `secondary()`, you are A) writing to `v` in the function, and B) you don't say `global v` anywhere in the function.  So Python says that inside that function, `v` is a unique variable local to that function.  But if `v` is local to the function, and your first reference to the variable in that function is:

```
v += 1
```

then `v` hasn't been assigned a value prior to this point.  Since this line of code first reads from `v`, and then writes a new value back to it, you get the error you're seeing because of the attempt to read from a variable that hasn't yet been assigned a value.

It seems pretty clear that what you need to do to fix this issue is to declare your `secondary` function as follows:

```
def secondary()
    global variable
    variable += 1
    return variable
```

The addition of `global variable` tells Python that your reference to `variable` is referring to the global variable with that name, even though you are writing to it.

I would suggest that in the future, you not name variables `variable`.  That can only lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In the secondary function, variable isn't defined. You would have to do `global variable`, which would make the variable accessible. Also, you call secondary twice, which would make the variable go up twice, not sure you would want that. Furthermore, secondary doesn't have a colon after the parentheses which creates a syntax error. Lastly, the code most likely isn't indented correctly, as the secondary variable is not indented, although the other code blocks are.